# Camel and specifying the properties file without hardcoding

Tags: spring, apache-camel, karaf, blueprint

Im trying to get a a separate config/properties file for Camel related stuff and other stuff. Using Blueprint but I guess that might as well be Spring in this particular case

As I understand it is good practice in Karaf to use the property-placeholder for config data. which will be searched for in the ../karaf/ect folder.

Nice, as we do not have a fixed coded path.I have that part working.

```
<blueprint ...
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="org.example.project" update-strategy="reload" id="prop">
        ...
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <camelContext id="myCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="watchfolder">
            <from uri="file:{{ENDPOINT.IN}}"/>
            <to uri="direct:test"/>
        </route>
```

../karaf/ect/org.example.project.cfg file:

```
ENDPOINT.IN=C:/Users/username/Documents/project/folderwatch
```

Within camelContext we alse have the possibility to use propertyPlaceholder. Works if I define it like this

```
...
            <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:C:/Users/username/Documents/project/camel.properties" />
...
```

and moved the property to file C:/Users/username/Documents/project/camel.properties.

But that is a fixed path inside my blueprint file. I thought It would be better to make it configurable for testing/working in different dev environments/... Just point to a different config file.

I would like to do this, which does not work:

```
...
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:{{CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE}}" />
...
```

../karaf/ect/org.example.project.cfg file:

```
CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE=C:/Users/username/Documents/project/camel.properties
```

Result is:

```
..
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: {{CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE}} (The system cannot find the file specified)
..
```

It seems the value is not being parsed as a property.
I tried variations like:

```
location="file:${CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE}" 
location="file:{{blueprint:CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE}}" 
location="file:{{blueprint:prop:CAMEL.PROPERTIES_FILE}}"
```

(These last tries were just gambling. I did not understand the meaning behind that functionality)

So ultimately, the question is:

**How to specify a variable camel properties file?**

I'm using: Karaf 4.0.0, Camel 2.15.3, Win7

Comment: Why introduce a second config file if you already have the blueprint cfg file? Just put all your properties in the cfg file and use `${my.property}` outside the camel context and `{{another.property}}` inside the Camel context to get the specified keys replaced with the value from the cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="${env:PROP_FILE_OS_ENV_LOC}"/>
```

where PROP_FILE_OS_ENV_LOC is a OS environment variable

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="${PROP_FILE_JVM_LOC}"/>
```

where PROP_FILE_JVM_LOC is a JVM property